# Making a query with a single row out

Tags: sql

[image]

Please help. The question is in the image.

Comment: Post your code and details not just images

Comment: Code goes into the question. Details and required information go into the question. The question goes into the question (*duh*).

Comment: Hi Brad! I could not find the better way of asking this specific question other than posting it within an image. I unfortunately do not have an ability to draw tables in question box.

Comment: @novichock One way is ask a question in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do *conditional* aggregation :

```
select id,
       sum(case when type = 'x' and location = 'L' then amount else 0 end) as sumofXandL,
       . . . 
from table t
group by id;
```